# Filter an array of objects with .filter

Tags: javascript, filter

If have a JSON object, how can I use.filter to filter my array based on a filters object.

```
data = [
   {month: 'Sep', name: 'Fred', department: 'Accounting'},
   {month: 'Sep', name: 'David', department: 'Sales'},
   {month: 'Oct', name: 'Jon', department: 'Sales'}
]

filters = {
    month: [],
    name: ['Jon'],
    department: ['Sales','Accounting']
}
```

Comment: Theres no 2d array here. Its unclear what you want to do

Comment: Excellent observation

Comment: I changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = [
 { month: 'Sep', name: 'Fred', department: 'Accounting' },
 { month: 'Sep', name: 'David', department: 'Sales' },
 { month: 'Oct', name: 'Jon', department: 'Sales' }
];

let filters = {
  month: [],
  name: ['Jon'],
  department: ['Sales', 'Accounting']
};

let matches = data.filter(function (o) {
  // iterate through keys of filter object
  for (const key in this) {
    // if filter array is empty and
    // value is not in filter array
    if (this[key].length > 0 && !this[key].includes(o[key])) {
      // object is not match
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  // if object passed every filter array
  // object is match
  return true;
}, filters);

console.log(matches);
```

A more compact way of writing it could be like this:

```js
let data = [
  { month: 'Sep', name: 'Fred', department: 'Accounting' },
  { month: 'Sep', name: 'David', department: 'Sales' },
  { month: 'Oct', name: 'Jon', department: 'Sales' }
];

let filters = {
  month: [],
  name: ['Jon'],
  department: ['Sales', 'Accounting']
};

let matches = data.filter(function (o) {
  return Object.keys(this).every(
    key => this[key].length === 0 || this[key].includes(o[key])
  );
}, filters);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: I dont see any advantage of `key of Object.keys(this)` over `key in filters`

Comment: @JonasW. one advantage is that the former does not iterate inherited enumerable keys, only own enumerable, but I do agree in this case it's easier to use `for...in`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const result = data.filter(entry => {
   for(var key in filters){
     if(filters[key].length && !filters[key].includes(entry[key]) )
        return false;
   }
   return true;
});
```

You could `filter` your *data* by checking every filter's key to exist in the object and that its value is included in the filtering array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `filter()` and `every()` methods.

```js
var data = [
   {month: 'Sep', name: 'Fred', department: 'Accounting'},
   {month: 'Sep', name: 'David', department: 'Sales'},
   {month: 'Oct', name: 'Jon', department: 'Sales'}
]

var filters = {
    month: [],
    name: ['Jon'],
    department: ['Sales','Accounting']
}

var result = data.filter(e => {
  return Object.keys(filters).every(f => {
    return filters[f].includes(e[f]) || !filters[f].length
  })
})


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.filter(obj => filters.month.indexOf(obj.month) > -1 && filters.name.indexOf(obj.name) > -1 && filters.department.indexOf(obj.department) > -1)
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Without teaching, you're just dumping out an answer, which is a bad answer.